# Jquery - rotate DIV by X degrees onScroll when at 50%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok, so this should be easy and I'm half way there but lack of sleep has me struggling with the basic math of it all.

I need to start rotating a DIV once the scroll point is at 50% - the '.thumb' DIV needs to start at it's CSS starting point, then at a scroll point of 50% start rotating, essentially simulating a "thumbs up" from half way down the screen. Then scrolling up resets the thumb in reverse.

*Two questions*:

- How do I get that dam rotating '.thumb' rotating to a standing position?
- And any suggestions on the code so far, is it going to be too expensive?

*Example Code & Fiddle*:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var wintop = $(window).scrollTop(),
      docheight = $('article').height(),
      winheight = $(window).height(),
      totalScroll = (wintop/(docheight-winheight)) * 100,
      progressBar = $('.progress-bar');

  // Note: too expensive polling??
  if (totalScroll >= 50) {
    // This bit is a mess and I can't figure it out yo.
    // Start rotating from 0 to 100 (or from 90deg t 0deg??)
    var rotate = (wintop / docheight) * 180;

    $('.progress-thumb .thumb').css({ transform: 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)' });
  }
  progressBar.css('width', totalScroll + '%');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/keazyj6f/2/

Thanks as always, appreciate all the sound advice

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution for 1st half of the question https://jsfiddle.net/keazyj6f/5/

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var wintop = $(window).scrollTop(),
      docheight = $('article').height(),
      winheight = $(window).height(),
      totalScroll = (wintop/(docheight-winheight)) * 100,
      progressBar = $('.progress-bar');

  // Note: too expensive polling??
  if (totalScroll >= 50) {
      // This bit is fucked and I can't figure it out yo.
      // Start rotating from 0 to 100 (or from 90deg t 0deg??)
      var rotate = (wintop / (docheight-winheight)) * 180;
      $('.progress-thumb .thumb').css({ transform: 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)' });
  } else {
    $('.progress-thumb .thumb').css({ transform: 'rotate(0deg)'});
  } 

  progressBar.css('width', totalScroll + '%');
});
```

```css
article {
  position: relative;
  height: 4000px;
  width: 100%;

  &:after {
    content: '50% Start rotating thumb';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #000;
  }
}
.container-progress {
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  background-color: white;
  content: "";
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;

  .progress-bar {
    position: relative;
    width: 0%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    z-index:99;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: #009dff;
    -webkit-transition: width .6s ease;
    -o-transition: width .6s ease;
    transition: width .6s ease;
     
    .progress-thumb {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0px;
      top: -28px;

      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;

      background-color: blue;

     .thumb {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 24px;
        top: 15px;

        width: 50px;
        height: 20px;

        transform-origin: center center;

        background-color: red;
      }
    }
  }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-progress">
    <div class="progress-bar">
        <div class="progress-thumb">
            <div class="thumb"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<article></article>
```

Hope this will solve your 1st part of the question. I will look into the next part.

You missed to subtract winheight from docheight 
`var rotate = (wintop / (docheight-winheight)) * 180;`

Comment: Hey mate, this was pretty close. It kicks off the initial rotation (50% marker) at a random angle, instead of the smooth "thumbs up" I was hoping for, but gave me enough to move forward based on the updated math. Cheers.

Comment: Are you looking a smooth "thumbs up" from 0% or 50% marker?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (totalScroll >= 50) {

      var rotate = (wintop / docheight) *** 120;** // change the value from 180 - 120

      console.log('rotate: ', rotate);
      $('.progress-thumb .thumb').css({ transform: 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)' });
  }
```

Hope it helps.